# What does the *= operator do?

Tags: php, operators

I've been looking through a few mock exams and study guides for PHP and I came across this example:

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
foreach ($a as $x)
    $x *= 2;
echo $a[0]  * $a[1]  * $a[2];
```

This returns `6`.

My question is: what exactly does the `*=` operator mean?

Comment: [What does this symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: @MarkBaker Useful question, but `*=` isn't mentioned there.

Comment: This example is really really bad as a teaching tool (it's either misguided or trying to show that non-reference `foreach` does not make changes stick -- in which case, why confuse the student with extra multiplications after the loop that have nothing to do with making that point?). Beware of that study guide.

Comment: I don't see who uvoted this question. This really doesn't show any research effort at all.

Comment: @AnotherTest I challenge you to Google a symbol like this. You won't find anything useful.

Comment: `$a*=b$ $a-=$b $a+=$b $a/=$b ....`  == ` $a= $a*$b,  $a= $a-$b,  $a= $a+$b,  $a= $a/$b, `

Comment: This is covered in the [PHP language reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php): *"In addition to the basic assignment operator, there are "combined operators" for all of the [binary arithmetic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php), array union and string operators that allow you to use a value in an expression and then set its value to the result of that expression."* Though I understand that it might not be easy to find if you don't know what to look for (*assignment* is the keyword here).

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Go to Google and start typing `php *=`. You do not even have to know the term "operator".

Comment: @DannyBeckett Who said anything about google? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: The study guide comes from Zend, I wasn't particularly interested in doing the exam I just wanted to have an idea of what kind of knowledge they would expect to pass it.

Comment: @AnotherTest If you're trying to find something out, you'd typically Google it. Searching for something like `php *=` yields utter crap.

Comment: @DannyBeckett If it's something related to the PHP core language, it'd typically search php.net.

Comment: @Jon Again, utter crap: [https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+*%3D+operator](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+*%3D+operator)

Comment: @AnotherTest **Good luck search php.net!** http://uk1.php.net/results.php?q=%2A%3D&l=en&p=all

Comment: @DannyBeckett He said "operator" in the question. So anyone would search for "operator" on the online documentation.

Comment: People, my point here is: trying to find out what a symbol does, in any language, inherently takes the mickey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a shortcut for:

```
$x = $x * 2
```

A syntax which dates back to C and accounts for natural (from a human's point of view) "multiply $x by 2", rather than programmatic "take $x value, multiply it by 2 and reassign back to $x" -- as Kernighan and Ritchie stated in their [The C programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29).

It can be applied to all numerical operators:

```
$x = $x + 2 <---> $x += 2
$x = $x - 2 <---> $x -= 2
$x = $x / 2 <---> $x /= 2
etc...
```

By the way, the printed value `6` it's not related.

Answer (score 3):

```
$x *= 2;
```

is nothing but

```
$x = $x * 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$x *= 2;` is the same as `$x = $x * 2;` (like `+=` and `-=` and `.=` etc)

Answer (score 1):

`+=`, `*=`, `/=` and `-=` are compound operators. In your code, it would expand to:

```
$x = $x * 2
```